# Downloaded images not showing in phone's gallery, flutter

Tags: android, image, flutter, storage, gallery

My flutter app is successfully downloading media to 'android/media/com.example.testapp/testapp/images/'. I can see them via file explorer but for some reason I am not able to see them in gallery. Earlier I was storing images outside of the android storage at that time Images were showing in gallery. I'm using mediascanner for this.

```dart
print(directory.path);//outputs /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.testapp/testapp/images/image1.jpg

MediaScanner.loadMedia(path: directory.path);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, you aren't telling the OS about new image or video, for this you need to use Android Intent or use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver, it will update the media files every time you save your file using this plugin

Comment: but it was working when i am saving images outside android folder

Comment: yes, because OS do not scan every directory, I had the same issue and resolved saving images and videos using that plugin, and problem was solved.

Comment: Yeah, the images are now showing in the gallery but it's not showing in the images folder like WhatsApp images are shown in a gallery in the WhatsApp images folder.